# pandas "DataFrame constructor not properly called" when given a list of Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of `pd.Series` stored as a Python `list`, and I want to create a `pd.DataFrame` with those Series as its *rows*. The following code works for the latest pandas version (1.1.3), but fails in my setup:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(ls_series)
```

```py
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

(Win)Python==3.6.1. pandas==0.19.2, numpy==1.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is convert list of Series to dict of Series and pass to [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
ls_series = [pd.Series([1,2,6], name='a'), 
             pd.Series([10,20,60], name='b'), 
             pd.Series([11,12,61], name='c')]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({x.name: x for x in ls_series}, orient='index')
print (df)
    0   1   2
a   1   2   6
b  10  20  60
c  11  12  61
```

Comment: These put the Series as columns, not rows. And the first one loses the Series names.

Comment: I kind of like this solution because mine implicitly sorts columns alphabetically (which I do not want)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `pd.concat` with `axis=1` will create a DataFrame with those Series as columns. Then just use `.transpose()` or `.T`:

```py
df = pd.concat(ls_series, axis=1).T
```